# Iteratation through variables of an objects (java)

Tags: java, loops, object, iterator, euclidean-distance

I have a class `Room` with the following constructor:

```
public Room (int x, int y, int z, int Stockwerk) {      
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.Stockwerk = Stockwerk;
}
```

In another `class` I want to calculate the similarity of two rooms by using the Euclidean distance. Therefore I want to `iterate` trough the `object` room to compare the first value(x) of room1 with the first value(x) of room2, the second(y) with the second(y) and so on. (The code below describes how I tried to get a result). Is there any option to iterate through the object room?

```
Iterator itrRoom1 = room1.iterator();
Iterator itrRoom2 = room2.iterator();

while (itrRoom1.hasNext()) {            
    while (itrRoom2.hasNext()) {
        int value1 = itrRoom1.next();
        int value2 = itrRoom2.next();
    }
    //this is the function how I get the similarity of two rooms (euclidean distance)
    squareSubtraction = squareSubtraction + Math.pow(Math.abs(value1 - value2)), 2); 
}

distance = Math.sqrt(squareSubtraction);
```

Comment: Why don't you use a 3D point class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it with a very complicated way and `Iterator` is not needed.

If you want to get the euclidean distance, you only have to parse these two instances of `Room` to be compared. I assume your `Room` class has the getters.

You can use the following method with the arbitrary number of arguments based on looping through of all instances of `Room` given.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    Room room1 = new Room(10,12,2,0);
    Room room2 = new Room(4,8,2,0);
    Room room3 = new Room(7,5,2,0);
    Room room4 = new Room(10,2,2,0);

    double result = similarity(room1, room2, room3, room4);
}

public static double similarity(Room ... r) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<r.length-1; i++) {
        double a = Math.pow(r[i].getX() - r[i+1].getX(), 2);
        double b = Math.pow(r[i].getY() - r[i+1].getY(), 2);
        sum += a + b;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(sum);
}
```

This is giving you the result:

> 9.38083151964686

Comment: So it is only possible to get the values over the getters? Isn't der anything like room.nextValue(), so you could write the whole part in one line of code: double value = Math.pow(r[i].nextValue() - r[i+1].nextValue(), 2); ?

Comment: I don't know the way using `Iterator` exactly to do that your data representation. In case of having these data stored as for example `ArrayList` you are able to loop them easier or use `Stream`, that takes the one line as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't iterate *fields* like that. You could iterate fields using reflection, but don't.

You only have 3 values. Just use them.

```
long dx = room1.getX() - room2.getX();
long dy = room1.getY() - room2.getY();
long dz = room1.getZ() - room2.getZ();
double distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
```

Note that `dx` and the others are declared `long`, so `dx * dx` won't overflow, and `dx * dx` is much faster than `Math.pow(dx, 2)`.

It's actually even **less code** than what you were trying to do.